# ajax http request not sending document.cookie on same domain

Tags: ajax, cookies, request

why is my ajax request not sending the document.cookie? i'm on the same domain!

here's my code:

```
document.cookie = "test=test";
  var query_url = 'http://example.com/dosomething';
    $.ajax({
        url: query_url,
        type: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        success: function(data){
            if(data === "OK") {
                //some code
            };

            if(data !== "OK") {
                //some code
            }

        },
        error: function(error){
                            console.log("===ERROR");
                            console.log(error);
                }, 

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after setting path to my document.cookie, my ajax request is sending it! the xhrfield is not necessary.

```
document.cookie = "test=test; path=/";
```

(edit):
my frontend URL is example.com/fe/app.html. By backend runs on example.com/ maybe that's the reason i need the "path=/" in my cookie